# How to make UIkit Object inherited From Custom NSObject

Tags: objective-c

i would like to create a some function in NSObject init method. and all my custom views inherited from it.
For example ,
[NSObject] <- [CustomNSObject] <- [UIResponder] <- [UIView] <- [CustomUIView] ;
[NSObject] <- [CustomNSObject] <- [UIResponder] <- [UIImageView] <- [CustomUIImageView];

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make `UIView` inherit from your custom class. If you want to add functionality to UIKit classes, you can do that with [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Comment: but i would like to add some code inside NSObject init function.
i think categories canot handle it

Comment: No!  Don't override any methods in categories, not the least of which being `-init` on the root class of **every useful ObjC object**